# How would you explain pressure to a school kid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure, education

suppose there is a squarish block (height 2 m) 1*1 on a table  and different forces are acting on it from top perpendicular to the surface on top .Suppose it is like one force is of 3N in the middle of the top face block and other force is like 2N 1/4 of the diagonal away from 1 corner on a diagonal What is the pressure?

The doubt is if forces are distributed unevenly what is the relevance?
if you say pressure 5N/m2 on the top of the block there would be many places where pressure would be  zero on the top of the block.I don't understand the relevance of it like if forces are evenly distributed then there could be a point forces can be unevenly distributed too .

***Please explain simply and kindly I am just a kid.***
[image]

Comment: Can you explain the force distribution part better, and maybe add an image showing the body and forces directions

Comment: In ideal scenarios, you don't have to worry about the unevenness; you just assume it. Pressure is then just $p=F/A$. (Unless you have to consider rotation, since an unevenly distributed force might cause an unbalanced torque around the centre-of-mass of the "plate" that makes up the surface - it doesn't sound like that in your case.) In real-life scenarios, the pressure varies over the surface, and you can't solve this without more knowledge about the material or force distribution. Not even if the force was exactly in the centre of a surface could you assume an evenly spread pressure.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose it is like one force is of 3N in the middle of the top face block and other force is like 2N 1/4 of the diagonal away from 1 corner on a diagonal What is the pressure?

In this case you are assuming your two forces are being applied at a point. Therefore, the pressure of each force is infinite, as the area is $0$.

If you specified how your forces are distributed in space, then you could determine a finite pressure for each force.

If you wanted to talk "on average" across the top of the block, then you could just take the sum of the forces divided by the area of the top face. This would give you an average pressure on the top face supplied by your forces.

Comment: So why is pressure relevant

Comment: @AllahMaalik If you stand on on foot on the ground, you would be fairly comfortable. If you try to stand on a nail on one foot (or maybe a somewhat duller spike) you will not feel comfortable. The force that is needed to support you isn't changing, but the pressure is different due to different areas over which the force is being applied.

Comment: I didn't downvote

Answer (score 0):

We do not typically use the term "pressure" when working only with point forces on hard surfaces. Pressure is force distributed over an area, or P = F/A. Since you use the word "block" I assume the block is solid.

However, if you were talking about a hollow box, the OUTSIDE of the top surface of the box, ignoring the atmosphere, experiences no force (hence no pressure), anywhere except where the forces are applied. However, if the box is filled with gas, and the top surface is free to slide up and down like a piston, then the INSIDE of the top surface will experience 5 N/m2, and the pressure of the gas will be 5 N/m2 also.